# iOS get width height of jpg file

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, image, jpeg

In my iOS app, I'm downloading jpeg images from the web, and I'm wondering how to find the correct width and height of the image so I can display it properly in my iOS app.

For example, 

[image]

How do I get the width and height of this jpg image?

Comment: Check my updated Answer hope its help's you.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

you can get Image Height and Width like:-

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
NSLog(@'image height: %f',image.size.height);
NSLog(@'image width: %f',image.size.width);
```

**UPDATE:-**

as per your URL you can get like:-

```
NSString *ImageURL = @"http://gigaom2.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/teacher-classroom.jpg";


    ImageURL =[ImageURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"img url ==%@",ImageURL);
    NSURL *imageUrl =[NSURL URLWithString:ImageURL];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    [inView setImage:image];
    NSLog(@"image height: %f",image.size.height);

    [lbl1 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2.0f",image.size.height]];
    [lbl2 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2.0f",image.size.width]];
```

your Screen look like:-

[image]

I just Create a Demo for You :) link is bellow

http://www.sendspace.com/file/7pp63a

Answer (score 4):

[**`UIImage`**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImage/size) has the property `size`

```
image.size.width
image.size.height
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using `UIImage` Size property.

Have a look at below:

```
UIImage *image;

NSLog(@'Width=%f and Height: %f',image.size.width, image.size.height);
```

Store your web image into "image" object and you will get Width & Height of the image.

Cheers!