# How to get the image width and height from image view in iOS

Tags: ios7, uiimageview, uiimage, size

i have one image as 640*960,and my image view has 300*300.i set the content mode the image view as aspect fit, now i load the image to the imageView it looks follow..

[image]

after loaded the image to the image view i need the width and height of the image from the imageView.

Comment: Please go through the following link-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14620279/ios-get-width-height-of-jpg-file

Answer (score 0):

You can get height and width of image in following way:

```
UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"paint5.png"];
int imgHeight =  image.layer.frame.size.height;
int imgWidth = image.layer.frame.size.width;
NSLog(@"height of image %i",imgHeight);
NSLog(@"widht of image %i",imgWidth);
```

Comment: this also give the width and height of  imageview only.not giving width and height of the image

Comment: UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"paint5.png"];
    
    int height  = image.size.height;
    int width = image.size.width;
    
    NSLog(@"Height of image is %i and width of image is %i",height,width);

Comment: yes i'm getting 300*300.this give only the actual image width and height.i need the image width and height after loaded into the imageView

Comment: did you try this one ?                                                                                 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"paint5.png"]; int height = image.size.height; int width = image.size.width; NSLog(@"Height of image is %i and width of image is %i",height,width

Comment: I tried this and this is working for me . try to put first static image in your project named with img.png and run this code: UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"];
    NSLog(@"height of image %f and width of image is %f",image.size.height,image.size.width);

Comment: Yes friend we can get the image width and height as you said , if the img.png is 400*450.i load that image to the imageView(300*300) means,before i load the image  it gives 400*450 after i load to the  imageView it gives only the 300*300 now i need to get the image width and height from the imageView

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

```
@import AVFoundation; 

UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"paint5.png"];
CGRect yourFrame = AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(imageView.image.size, imageView.bounds);
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(yourFrame));
```

I think thats what u are looking for.

[AV Foundation Functions Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundation_Functions/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect)